# Distribution of classes in neural network batches

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

I'm creating a neural network for classifying input data. When using batches, do I need to ensure a somewhat uniform distribution of classes per batch? Or can I simply split up my data in any which way?

Comment: How is an answer for this different for a NN than for another alg? Just curious.

Comment: @CharlieParker No idea. Probably the same, but I figured I should err on the side of over information.

Answer (score 2):

Uniform distribution of classes per batch is best, since it's a better approximation of the gradient computed on the entire training set. In practice, batches are typically chosen randomly.

[1] addresses the question:

> As for any stochastic gradient descent method (including
>   the mini-batch case), it is important for efficiency of the estimator that each example or minibatch
>   be sampled approximately independently. Because
>   random access to memory (or even worse, to
>   disk) is expensive, a good approximation, called incremental
>   gradient (Bertsekas, 2010), is to visit the
>   examples (or mini-batches) in a fixed order corresponding
>   to their order in memory or disk (repeating
>   the examples in the same order on a second epoch, if
>   we are not in the pure online case where each example
>   is visited only once). In this context, it is safer if
>   the examples or mini-batches are first put in a random
>   order (to make sure this is the case, it could
>   be useful to first shuffle the examples). Faster convergence
>   has been observed if the order in which the
>   mini-batches are visited is changed for each epoch,
>   which can be reasonably efficient if the training set
>   holds in computer memory.

---

[1] Bengio, Yoshua. "[Practical recommendations for gradient-based training of deep architectures.](http://arxiv.org/abs/1206.5533)" Neural Networks: Tricks of the Trade. Springer Berlin Heidelberg, 2012. 437-478.

Comment: I am skeptical that this works in general (I know the no free lunch theorem). Consider a distribution where the classes are skewed. If you had accesses to the true distribution then you'd have gradients pointing to classes that are more common. This should be pretty common in most data sets too though.

Comment: @CharlieParker Once the main classes are decently learnt, gradients would start go to the minority classes.

Comment: but the size of a mini-batch on average will still have even distributions. Why would it shift to any other classes, it should still learn them evenly, no?

Comment: @Charliearker If classes are skewed, and mini-batches randomly drawn, then mini-batches are skewed.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood the question. I thought the OP wanted to make an even distribution even though the data set wasn't like that. Of course the mini-batches on average will be skewed if the distribution is skewed.

Comment: @CharlieParker From understanding OP just wants to know whether he needs to ensure a somewhat uniform distribution of classes per batch (my answer being no)